# How to focus an input type text automatically after window.location.href?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I've got this problem since yesterday and I cannot solve it could you please help me?

I want to trigger a focus so when the page is reloaded by the window.location.href function and $_GET is set on the url, it focuses automatically an input type text with the id productCode.

I've tried everything with Jquery, the .focus() method does not work for me.

What can i do?

Thank you in advance guys,

**Solution By user toor**

```
<input <?php if (isset($_GET['nit'])) echo 'autofocus'; ?> ...>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't sure I understand you clearly, but maybe you may insert "autofocus" parameter into the input tag required.

```
<input autofocus id="productCode" ... >
```

Comment: Correct answer haha, you saved my life dude, is there anyway to assign it through jquery? i mean i want this to only happen if $_GET variable is set on the url.

Comment: <input <?php if (isset($_GET)) echo 'autofocus'; ?> ...>

Comment: What you mean? it worked like that,  autofocus attribute can be assigned through Jquery right?

Comment: Sorry... I've edit my comment above. You may set it by php.

Comment: Everyone mark this as the correct answer, thank you very much.